# Module dismissKeyboard issue in react native?

Tags: react-native

error: Error: Unable to resolve module `dismissKeyboard` from `src\common\autoHideKeyboard.js`: dismissKeyboard could not be found within the project

autohidekeyboard.js

```
import {TouchableWithoutFeedback,View} from 'react-native'
import React from "react";
const dismissKeyboard = require('dismissKeyboard')

export default (WrappedComponent) => {
    class AutoHideKeyboard extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={dismissKeyboard}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            )
        }
    }
    return AutoHideKeyboard;
}
```

using it as below

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';
import _ from 'lodash';

import { scaleSize } from 'src/common/screenUtil';
import HocErrorCatch from 'src/common/error';
import AutoHideKeyboard from 'src/common/autoHideKeyboard';
import Header from 'src/components/header';
import FltLinearGradient from 'src/components/linearGradient';
import RadioButton from 'src/components/radioButton';
import RadioGroup from 'src/components/radioGroup';

import * as FlightSearch from 'src/model/flightsearch';
import CxcargoErampAPI from 'src/api/cxcargo-eramp';
import ExceptionUtils from 'src/utils/exception-util';
import BusinessUtils from 'src/utils/business-util';
import { CurrentSession } from 'src/config/config';

import * as Styles from 'src/common/styles';
import * as CoreConfig from 'src/config/config';
import * as Images from '~assets/images';
import * as Colors from 'src/styles/colors';

const _fs = Styles.FlightSearch;
/**
 * SPIHOHC
 */
@inject('store')
@observer
@HocErrorCatch
@AutoHideKeyboard
export default class SearchDetail extends React.Component {
```

after running react-native run-android getting above issue. is there any clue to resolve or root cause for this issue.

Thank you for help

Comment: Can you share more context? i.e. how you're defining your function and how you're calling it, etc.

Comment: @Johan i have updated the question with mpre details

Comment: I don't see where `dismissKeyboard` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

> How about use `Keyboard.dismiss()` in your app

### Answer

The way I see it, `dismissKeyboard` mean `Keyboard.dismiss()`
That error means there is no `dismissKeyboard` module or file in your project.

And I search is there some module like `DismissKeyboard` in npm, But there is no module naming that. So I guess your co-worker(I guess It is not your own code) mean `Keyboard.dismiss()`

`Keyboard.dismiss()` is React-Native api for dismiss keyboard.

```js
import {TouchableWithoutFeedback, View, Keyboard} from 'react-native'
import React from "react";

export default (WrappedComponent) => {
    class AutoHideKeyboard extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={()=>Keyboard.dismiss()}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            )
        }
    }
    return AutoHideKeyboard;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the api exposed by React Native which is

> **Keyboard.dismiss()**

And your code will look something like this

```
import React from 'react'
import {TouchableWithoutFeedback, View, Keyboard} from 'react-native'

export default function BaseComponent(props) {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss()}>
            {props.children} //child elements
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
```

PS- Have used a functional component.